# Delay in triggering Flink checkpointing(S3 backend) due to state.checkpoints.num-retained config

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Following is my Flink checkpoint configs and we have S3 as backend. We are running this flink job(version: 1.17.0) in EMR cluster

```
checkpoint-interval : 70000
min-pause-between-checkpoint : 15000
max-concurrent-checkpoint : 1
checkpoint-type: unaligned
TolerableCheckpointFailureNumber :2
Checkpoint-mode : atleast-once
incremental-checkpointing: true
state.backend: filesystem
state.checkpoints.dir: s3p://checkpoint-sp-test/_entropy_/
s3.entropy.key: _entropy_
s3.entropy.length: 1
presto.s3.connect-timeout: 1m
presto.s3.socket-timeout: 1m
presto.s3.max-connections: 6500
state.checkpoints.num-retained: 3
high-availability.type: zookeeper
```

Total job parallelism : 5.5K

With above config, ideally flink checkpointing should happen on every 70 sec interval, but I am seeing a trigger delay of 5-20 mins on every checkpoint[Screenshot attached].

I was also able to figure out what is causing this delay. It is checkpoint blocking deletion flow which gets trigger before every checkpoint call. This checkpoint deletion flow is controlled by "state.checkpoints.num-retained" setting, if I set state.checkpoints.num-retained= 6000000(with any big number), all checkpoints happens on every 70 sec interval. One of the solution I was thinking of adding S3 lifecylce rule in checkpoint bucket to clean all checkpoint after 1 day.

Above will work but there is a side effect of setting "state.checkpoints.num-retained" to something very big number. I am seeing this side effect on new job manager election. Whenever new job manager is getting elected, it is first trying to fetch number of checkpoints configured on "state.checkpoints.num-retained" setting. If it set it to big, it is just struggling to fetch infinite number of old checkpoints and job does not able to start ever.

Any suggestion for fixing this issue will be very appreciated!!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up updating s3-fs-presto code for not calling s3-delete api for checkpoint cleanup and added s3 lifecycle cycle rule to clean up all old checkpoint after 2 days

Answer (score 0):

First, Flink periodically deletes old checkpoints to free up storage space. This cleanup process is controlled by the state.checkpoints.num-retained setting. When you set it to a very large number, Flink will retain a large number of checkpoints, and as a result, the cleanup process may take a long time because it needs to check and possibly delete a large number of old checkpoints. When a new job manager is elected, it needs to recover the state of the Flink job. This involves fetching the metadata and potentially some data from the retained checkpoints to restore the state. If you have set state.checkpoints.num-retained to an extremely large number, the job manager may struggle during recovery because it has to process a massive number of checkpoints, which can be time-consuming and resource-intensive.

I suggest you set an reasonable number using S3 lifecycle rules to automatically clean up old checkpoints after a certain period.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just set this state.checkpoints.num-retained = 3, even then I am seeing delay of 5-20 mins in checkpoint trigger process. with just 3 as number, this 20 mins delay looks very unjustifiable

Comment: It seems that you didn't remove the previous old checkpoints. Try to empty them first.

Comment: hmm. I tried with new empty bucket but still the same observation[Attached screenshot]. just fyi, I enabled snappy compression on checkpoint [env.getConfig().setUseSnapshotCompression(true);], also using entropy feature of checkpointing. not sure any of this can cause it

Comment: or could it be because of state size of 10-100GB, its taking time to delete this many data? I am trying with less state size now if that changes anything

Comment: Oh no, the size is too large. The size of each individual state is by default limited to 5 MB. Did you modify the state size?

Comment: In terms of the optimised state size, you can also try to partition it, or use state TTL to expire old state data.

Comment: I can't time it out because we may need it for longer duration.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have chosen the filesystem state backend, which doesn't support incremental checkpointing (despite the configuration you have set). So every checkpoint is a full checkpoint. And you have rather high parallelism (5500) in combination with many stateful operators. This means every checkpoint will contain 10s of thousands of files, which is not something S3 can handle quickly.

The RocksDB state backend is better at handling this much state, but it is slower.

Comment: Thanks David for taking a look. I updated the filesystem to [state.backend: rocksdb] but still seeing same delay. I also reduced the parallelism from 5.5K to 3.5K. I looked at s3 cloudtrail logs and seeing it is calling HeadObject request before each deleteObject call for each file.  I am suspecting with state size of ~50GB(~3-5K file), it is taking time to call HEAD/DeleteObject on all of them

Comment: One of the thing I am not able to understand is why delete old checkpoint call is a blocking call. It should be an async call and should never impact triggering of new checkpoints.